# Ajax facebook post with php

Tags: php, ajax, facebook, api

Okay so I am trying to post to facebook using ajax. The problem is I am getting that I am not logged in. This is the page that is being requested. config just includes my facebook app authentication details. I guess I just don't understand what needs to be done everything that I have tried has returned 0 (no user) when trying to do this request with ajax.

```
<?php
require_once 'includes/config.php';

//Including facebook php sdk file
require_once 'includes/php-sdk/facebook.php';

//Creating our application instance
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
            'appId' => APP_ID,
            'secret' => APP_SECRET,
            'cookie' => true
        ));

//Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
    try {
        // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
        $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken(); 
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log($e);
        $user = null;
    }
    //In order to post to the page later on we need to generate an Access Token for that page, to do this we get me-accounts in the following api call
    $accounts = $facebook->api('/me/accounts');
}
```

Comment: not quite sure how I got it working, but currently it looks to me like you're doing nothing with the $access_token variable. also, this is PHP using CURL and not AJAX

Comment: I know, in the snippet I'm not doing anything with it, the point is I'm never getting a chance to do anything with it as the ($user) is always false.

Comment: read some thing about oAuth and access tokens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php

where it says

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '344617158898614',
  'secret' => '6dc8ac871858b34798bc2488200e503d',
));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();

// We may or may not have this data based on whether the user is logged in.
//
// If we have a $user id here, it means we know the user is logged into
// Facebook, but we don't know if the access token is valid. An access
// token is invalid if the user logged out of Facebook.

if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}

// Login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
}
```

Try this code, it might be possible that you have never loggedin with a facebook account for the API to use (in this case im referring to the getLogoutUrl() and getLoginUrl() bit of code) in which case you would need to refer the user to the $loginUrl using for example:

```
header("location: $loginUrl");
```

Comment: Okay, so maybe this will help find a solution. Here are the steps I am using that makes this work. If I go to the targeted page and request it directly, I have to refresh the page a few times then it connects to facebook, after the page is connected to facebook I am able to go back and submit the form with the ajax request as I need. Any ideas?

Comment: The resolution for me was to include the javascript sdk. Still not convinced that this the the correct or only way to do it but it works.